# Why do no user-agents implement the CSS cursor style for video elements

Tags: html, firefox, css, webkit, html5-video

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to change the CSS property for `cursor` on a default HTML5 `video` element. So far, my testing has concluded:

1. No user-agents (browsers) implement `cursor: pointer` by default. So you are left with the normal OS arrow/control indicator
2. When you attempt to set `cursor: pointer`, the user-agents will change the cursor ONLY when the cursor is not over clickable elements within the `video` element... ie: play, pause, seek, mute, fullscreen.
3. This seems to be reverse the implementation of what SHOULD happen. The clickable elements of the `video` tag (control bar, center play button) should get the cursor style...or hell, just apply it to the whole thing.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: 2) Works in the firefox 19.0 over the controls.  The entire video is one big clickable element as well.  Clicking somewhere other than the controls toggles play/pause.

Comment: Does HTML5 state that the cursor over a video *should be* or *must be* a pointer and not up to the UA to choose? In CSS, the default is `cursor: auto`.

Comment: @Jrod Cool - not sure I tested it in 19 yet.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm not suggesting that it should be forced at all, but `cursor: auto` should be `pointer` when an item is clickable, no?

Comment: @tvpmb, no, it should not. It's only necessary for elements that don't otherwise present an affordance of clickability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For webkit you can target their pseudo elements

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel

video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button

video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container

video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider

video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button

video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline

video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display

video::-webkit-full-page-media::-webkit-media-controls-panel

video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container

video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display

video::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button

video::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button

video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button

video::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button

video::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button

video::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button
```

**Update**

Extended list of webkit pseudo elements: https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334

Comment: Crazy but also kind of genius.  Using the pseudo elements you could create a video player with matching styles to the rest of your site.

Comment: @Jrod Awesome man. I didn't think to look through the *cough* extensive list of pseudo elements. This should make the boss happy. Yes, for some reason it matters...LOL

Comment: @tvpmb I didn't know they existed until you asked the question so we both learned something today!

Comment: FWIW - Look what I found, this is only webkit, but good for reference either way: https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334

Comment: Exactly where I got them from ha. I'll add the link to the answer to give it better visibility for future users.

Comment: Here's also a list for Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS_Reference%2FMozilla_Extensions

Answer (score -1):

> Why do no user-agents implement the CSS cursor style for video elements?

Because there's no need for it

> This seems to be reverse the implementation of what SHOULD happen.

What do you think "should" happen? Pointers are not necessary for interactive elements. For example, if you hover over the scroll bar your arrow stays an arrow. In fact, most buttons for most computer software do not change the cursor. It's not necessary, as the hover & focus states of interactive elements are enough to afford clickability.

The reason `cursor: pointer` is common on the web, and the reason it's necessary is due to hyperlinks. Hyperlinks don't react on hover by default. A pointer is used to cue the user that the link *can* be clicked on.

For `<video>` elements, there are sufficient hover states that there's no need for the cursor to change.