# How to customize html5 audio player

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm doing a **html5 audio player** so I'm trying to use a custom player. I don't want to use the default `<audio>` tag interface. I want to do my own html/css styles for the player.

My actual code(it works)

```
if('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
    var myAudioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
    }

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://96.47.236.72:8364/;', true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.addEventListener('load', bufferSound, false);
    request.send();

    function bufferSound(event) {
      var request = event.target;
      var source = myAudioContext.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = myAudioContext.createBuffer(request.response, false);
      source.connect(myAudioContext.destination);
      source.noteOn(0);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EY54q/1/

Does someone know how can to edit this player style, or do something to use my own html/css code to execute this player?

Comment: Check this one out

[Editing audio player][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag

Comment: It's alright to have a link to a working jsfiddle, but it also helps to have the relevant code in the question itself (links aren't valid forever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can completely make your own style. just forget about the controls option (you can simply use `controls` and do not need to use `controls="controls"`). Just create buttons/divs/whatever, style them, and add an eventlistener that controls the audio interface:

html:

```
<button id="playpause">play
    <!--you can style the content with anything!-->
</button>
<audio id="player">
    <source src="http://96.47.236.72:8364/;" />
</audio>
```

JS:

```
window.player = document.getElementById('player');
document.getElementById('playpause').onclick = function () {
    if (player.paused) {
        player.play();
        this.innerHTML = 'pause';
    } else {
        player.pause();
        this.innerHTML = 'play';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LqM9D/1/

I see you are also using the audio api. Please note that you can't just dump an audio file in a buffer. It needs to be decoded to raw PCM. This takes a lot of time. A really easy method is to create a source node which is linked to the audio element:

```
var source = context.createMediaElementSoure(player); //we defined player in the first block of code
```

To make your page a bit more cross-browser capable:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
context = new AudioContext();
```

Edit:

[I think you want to know what else you can do with the  element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).
You can also make a slider for the timeline, and a volume slider/mute button, although I'd prefer the latter two to do that on a gainnode at the end of a line of filters and such.

Comment: Glad I could help! I made an audioplayer with a friend, so I have some knowledge of it (It uses the audioAPI and webRTC) :) If you want to know anything else, just ask!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible via "shadow dom". You just need to enable it in your browser and write styles for elements, that will arrive.

As I understend - it is browser specific feature. But for webkit-based styling of "shadow dom" work perfect.
There is not so many info, however this feature already used in full. For example see this question: [Why do no user-agents implement the CSS cursor style for video elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126921/)
If you enable displaying shadow dom in inspector setting, you will se how it works. (Also there is public list with selectors list - https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334)

For other browsers you need check support of working with "shadow dom".

Comment: There is not so many info. I update my unswer. This feature is still undocumented and is just a way for implementing GUI of new complex elements in html. So I suggest for use @MarijnS95 answer.