# HTML5 audio element - change track color

Tags: css, html, html5-audio

I'm using simplest html5 audio element like this

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto">
    <source src="Happy_Boy_End_Theme.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="podcasts/Happy_Boy_End_Theme.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

this result:
[image]

I want to

1) change the height of the control - tried these options nothing worked:

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto" height="350px">
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto" style="height: 350px;">
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto" style="height: 50%;">
```

2) Want to change its built in blue color sliders to red - without "building" my own player.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684398/how-to-customize-html5-audio-player you may find this previous stackoverflow question useful! :)

Comment: @DanVinnicombe that's actually the **opposite** of what I'm asking I DO want to use the default audio tag and not customizing it by myself like he does, Also since 2014 many changes have been introduced to the audio tag with HTML5

Answer (score 3):

Sorry,  in WinJS is an HTML5 control and currently there is no way to style by using CSS. Instead if you need a custom styled audio player, you could implement it by writing JavaScript code, or use some 3rd party library.

Comment: yep I know I can embed 3rd party, I googled for solutions prior of asking here. since I didn't find any, was hoping one of the guys here hacked it some how.

Answer (score -1):

Some styling can be achieved with javascript. See https://serversideup.net/style-the-html-5-audio-element/ for details

Comment: please avoid adding links as it may become invalid in near future.

Comment: What's the recommended approach then?

Comment: Try explaining code here with sample code snippets.